# Does a certain quartic quadrivariate polynomial fall within any known category?

Tags: polynomials, quartics

I've encountered the following quartic quadrivariate polynomial,
\begin{equation}
\left(w^2-1\right) x^2-w^2-2 w x y z+\left(y^2-1\right) \left(z^2-1\right).
\end{equation}
Does it correspond to any recognizable, previously-studied surface (if equated to 0)?